# Extract minutes to hour in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datediff

Controller Code

```
public function profile()
{
    
    $form = Form::all();

    $minute = 60;
    $hour = 60 * $minute;
    
    foreach ($form as $pro) 
    {
        $totalhour = $pro->diffInMinutes & $hour;
        dd($totalhour);
    }
    return view('dashboards.dashboard', compact('form','totalhour'));
}
```

the result dd : 12102

how displays total hour with conversion to hour and the rest minutes like (10hours, 20minute)

Answer (score 0):

You can find minutes like this

```
12102 % 60
= 40
```

You can find hours like this

```
(12102 - 42) / 60
= 201
```

Finally, you got 201 hours and 42 minutes

Comment: ok thanks its work,
i am showing to view using chartjs. data: {!!json_encode($totalhour)!!}, but on the chart not respond the $totalhour

Answer (score 0):

```
$minutes = 12102;
$formatted_time = floor($minutes / 60) . ' hours '. ($minutes -   floor($minutes / 60) * 60) .' minutes';
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the code does and how it helps.